# smbspool disappeared after today's update

Tags: printing, samba

smbspool and its symbolic link in the cups backend directory disappeared after today's update to 18.04 and I can't print any more. apt-get says samba is up to date. How can I get smbspool back?

Comment: Reinstalled samba-client, got smbspool (and smb backend link) back. Printing still not working any more.